# php page called from Joomla menu unable to capture logged in user info

Tags: joomla

We have an application running in Joomla . There is a menu option say 'My Data' - on clicking it will open a php page in an iframe . In this target php we want to capture the current logged in user details where we are facing the problem.

We have used `JFactory::getUser()` but it is not showing anything . Although if any specific id is passed as parameter to getuser then that id's details are coming . PFB the code . Can someone please help us. Thanks in advance .

```
/*******Start of code*********/

define('_JEXEC', 1);

define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php')) {

    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {

    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));

    require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';

}

require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';

$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

$app->initialise();

$user =& JFactory::getUser();

echo 'User name: ' . $user->username . '<br />'; echo 'Real name: ' . $user->name . '<br />';

$specificuser =& JFactory::getUser(403);

echo 'Specific User name: ' . $specificuser->username . '<br />'; echo 'Specific Real name: ' . $specificuser->name . '<br />';

/******eof code********/
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this approach which reloads the Joomla framework you could just inspect the session object, this is a dump from Joomla in debug mode:

```
Session
__default
    session.counter ⇒ 13
    session.timer.start ⇒ 1363124213
    session.timer.last ⇒ 1363162265
    session.timer.now ⇒ 1363162286
    session.client.browser ⇒ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
    registry ⇒ {}
        user
            id ⇒ 0
            name ⇒
            username ⇒
```

Comment: Hi- I just commented the below two lines in the above code      $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

$app->initialise();
and replaced this with getsesssion which tells me there is no session object . Does this indicate that the session object is not captured in the target page ?

Comment: try using $_SESSION super-variable or read more here:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php

the idea is to do this behind Joomla's back, so you just access sessions through normal php functions

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/libraries/joomla/factory.php' );
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');

$user = JFactory::getUser();

echo 'User name: ' . $user->username . '<br />'; 
echo 'Real name: ' . $user->name . '<br />';

$specificuser = JFactory::getUser(403);

echo 'Specific User name: ' . $specificuser->username . '<br />'; 
echo 'Specific Real name: ' . $specificuser->name . '<br />';
```

Hope this helps